# I cannot get a image to the bottom of my bootstrap DIV

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot get my image to the bottom of my DIV (that is boostrap DIV what is probably causing the problem)

```
<section id="page-portfolio">
    <div class="portfolio-item" id="item-1">
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
             <img src="img/mac-devices-small.png" class="img-responsive"/>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="portfolio-item" id="item-2">
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
             <img src="img/mac-devices-small.png" class="img-responsive"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#page-portfolio {
  height: 1300px;
}

.portfolio-item {
   height: 45%;
   width: 100%;
}

#item-1 {
   background-image: url("../img/client-fb.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: top;
   position: relative;
}

#item-1 img {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Any ideas to workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` element has an `id` of "item-2" yet your selector is targeting `#item-1`. Change your CSS selectors to either:

```css
#item-1, #item-2 { ... }
#item-1 img, #item-2 img { ... }
```

Or:

```css
.portfolio-item img { ... }
```

Comment: I disabled the positioning of the image of item-2 because I first wanted to fix the picture in section-1. I should have commented out item-2.